# Azure pipelines not being triggered

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a yml in my repo, with the following trigger

```
trigger:
batch: true
branches:
  include:
  - prod
paths:
include:
  - src/deploy/*
  - ref/static/*
  - azure-pipelines-prod.yml
exclude:
  - '*'
```

As seen, I was the trigger to run only when the specific files are changed.
When I am pushing changes to the yaml or the other included files, the build is not being triggered, What is the issue here?

Comment: Is it a new pipeline definition? If so, you have to first (manually) create a pipeline, and pointing it at you new yaml. It is not automatically picked up anymore by Azure Devops if it is a new pipeline definition in your repo.

Comment: @JarroVGIT - yes the pipeline is pointed to this specific yml.

Comment: You exclude everything, didn't notice it the first time, sorry. The `'*'` overrides the includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Miao Tian-MSFT for the answer.

I moved the yaml to a folder instead of keeping it in the root directory. The exclude * line will exclude everything unless it is kept in a folder.

```
trigger:
batch: true
branches:
 include:
 - prod
paths:
include:
 - src/deploy/*
 - ref/static/*
 - src/azure-pipelines-prod.yml
exclude:
 - '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code doesn't seem to be indented correctly. (Maybe there is just a problem with the pasting format when copied here.)

When I tested your trigger directly, I found that the pipeline can be triggered normally when the files in the `- src/deploy/* - ref/static/` folder are changed. But when the content in `azure-pipelines-prod.yml` is modified, the pipeline will not be triggered.

Then I deleted the `exclude - '*'` part. Now when I modify the content in `azure-pipelines-prod.yml`, the pipeline will be triggered. It seems that the `exclude` command excludes `azure-pipelines-prod.yml`.

I can trigger my pipeline with the following trigger.

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - prod
  paths:
    include:
      - src/deploy/*
      - ref/static/*
      - azure-pipelines-prod.yml
```

[image]

Comment: The requirement is to trigger the pipeline only for those specific files, hence removing the exclude section does not serve my purpose

Comment: Hi @JohnWick, if you want to trigger the pipeline only for those specific files, you only need to add them to the `include` section.  As mentioned in [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths), _If you exclude a path, you cannot also include it unless you qualify it to a deeper folder. For example, if you exclude /tools then you could include /tools/trigger-runs-on-these._ Your `azure-pipelines-prod.yml` is not a deeper folder when you exclude `'*'`  path .

Comment: your suggestion worked. Thanks! I moved the yml to a folder and the include exclude works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the **excloud "*"** or take the example of below:

```
trigger:
batch: true
branches:
  include:
  - prod
paths:
include:
  - src/deploy/*
  - ref/static/*
  - azure-pipelines-prod.yml
exclude:
  - src/deploy/test.yml
```

- if edit **src/deploy/test.yml** will not trigger the pipeline, but if other files or folders in **src/deploy/** modified, the pipeline runs.

---

If there are both **include** and **exclude**, which exclude should be the sub item of the include.